# Number of Non-Crossing Spanning Trees in $K_n$ through given edge

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Spanning Trees of the Complete Graph Avoiding a Given Tree](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/59100/spanning-trees-of-the-complete-graph-avoiding-a-given-tree)

Two edges $\{a,b\}, \{c,d\}$ are crossing if $a<c<b<d$.

How many non crossing spanning trees in $K_n$ exist which contain a given edge?
The idea of letting two trees grow from the vertices of the fixed edge doesn't guarantee that the resulting tree is non-crossing.

Comment: Oh you're right, I couldnt find that, so let me change my question to the more advanced problem.

Comment: Do you mean you have a fixed drawing of the complete graph graph on n vertices in the plane? If so, are the edges always straight line segments or do you allow curved edges?

Comment: @Joseph Malkevitch  No its an abstract graph, see my definition of crossing

Comment: The proof in the http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/59100/spanning-trees-of-the-complete-graph-avoiding-a-given-tree question won't work here

Comment: @Fred  So the edges of the complete graph come with distinct labels which can be compared in size?

Comment: No but the vertex set can be regarded as {1,...,n}